# Laravel order una consulta por un campo de la tabla relacionada

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
  $logs->whereHas('file',function ($q) use($orderByDir)
            {
                $q->orderBy('nombre_real',$orderByDir);
            });
```

la consulta esta fragmentada en varios trozos pero donde no haace lo esperado es aqui.
`file` es una relacion `1 File - N Logs` , la variable `$orderBy` hace referencia al tipo de ordenacion `ASC/DESC` pero siempre ordena de forma `asc` sin importar el valor de la var.

**Amplicación de pregunta:**

Este es el `controller`, encargado de hacer busquedas avanzadas segun que parametros recibe por `$request`. Como se puede observar en los comentarios todo funciona menos la ultima parte, ordenación. Si veis que use `paginate()` en ves de `get()` es porque necesito pasar el **data paginada** ya que estoy usando un paquete de datatable de vuejs que necesita eso.

```
public function searching(Request $request)
    {

        $length = $request->input('length');
        $orderBy = $request->input('column','created_at'); //Index
        $orderByDir = $request->input('dir', 'asc');
        $searchValue = $request->input('search','');
        $userId = auth()->user()->id;
        $logType = $request->input('logType',null);
        $request = $request->all();

        //main searching
        $logs = Log::with(['type','file']);


        // //search  -  file name (working !)
        $logs->whereHas('file',function ($q) use($userId,$searchValue,$orderBy,$orderByDir)
        {
            $q->where('nombre_real','like','%'.$searchValue.'%')
            ->where('user_id',$userId);
        });

        // //log type searching (work !)
        if ($logType != null) {
            $logs->whereHas('type',function ($q) use($logType)
            {
                $q->select('id')->where('name','like','%'.$logType.'%');
            });
        }

        //doing ...
        //sorting on this way when user doesnt wants order by related tables
        if ($orderBy === 'file.nombre_real' and $orderByDir === 'asc') {
            // $data =  $logs->paginate($length)->sortBy('file.nombre_real');
            $data =  $logs->paginate($length)->sortBy('file.nombre_real');
        }
       else if ($orderBy === 'file.nombre_real' and $orderByDir === 'desc') {
            $data =  $logs->paginate($length)->sortByDesc('file.nombre_real');
        }
        else{
            $logs->orderBy($orderBy,$orderByDir);
            $data =  $logs->paginate($length);

        }


        return new DataTableCollectionResource($data);

    }
```

Comment: pone la consulta completa, sino no se entiende el contexto.

Comment: @rendor9 dicho y hecho

Comment: Estás seguro de que `$orderByDir` está recibiendo un valor distinto a `asc`?

Comment: @L.Flor con el xdebug activado y creando un breackpoint antes del return del controller he probado cuando con asc y desc a ver s icambiaba y el valor cambiaba.

Comment: vamos con lo básico, revisa que realmente este pasando por ese ELSE que contiene el ordenamiento, ponele alguna otra condición en ese else y a ver si la cumple.

Comment: que llega en $orderBy ? ahi esta el tema.